# Very simple function gives no output ( Python 3.7)

Tags: python, function, output

First-Timer here :)

The very simple function geome(x) gives no output, eventhough the exact same code works fine outside of the function (see "z = list ...").

What am I doing wrong?

Would very much appreciate some help or hintsThank you.

```
from operator import truediv

x = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]

z = list(map(truediv, x[1:], x[:-1])) # This Works perfectly fine! >>> Geometric
if all(num == z[0] for num in z):
    print('Geometric')


def geome(x):
    z = list(map(truediv, x[1:], x[:-1])) 
    if all(num == x[0] for num in z):
        print('Geometric')

geome(x) # Doesn't work, even though it is the same code as above, only inside of a function. >>>
```

Comment: They’re different operations; one works on `z[0]`, the other on `x[0]`.

Comment: The last x in the function should be a z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `geome` implements something different to what you have outside. In the `if` clause you changed `z[0]` to `x[0]`, so `geome` should be like this instead:

```py
def geome(x):
    z = list(map(truediv, x[1:], x[:-1])) 
    if all(num == z[0] for num in z):
        print('Geometric')
```